# How to sum certain numbers from a column based of two criterions?

Tags: google-sheets

**I have this formula:**

```
=ROUND(sumif(Percent, ">0")/COUNTIF(Percent, ">0"), 3)*100 & "%" & " : " & ROUND(sumif(Percent, "<0")/COUNTIF(Percent, "<0"), 3)*100 & "%"
```

That displays two percentages `(ex: 4.5% : -3.9%)` that correctly calculates the percentage averages from the percentage column.

I have another column, called Style, which has three types of letter combinations (`BRB`, `EP`, and `RM`).

What I am having difficulty with is recreating the above formula but that only picks up all the `BRB`, `EP`, and `RM` separately and displays their averages aside from the total averages.

Logically, it seems straightforwards with an `IF()` and an `AND()` to pick up the correct rows but I can't seem to get it to work.

**This is what I have (this is just the left half of the top formula):**

```
=ROUND(sumif(AND(Percent= ">0",Style="BRB")/COUNTIF(AND((Percent= ">0",Style="BRB")) 3)*100))
```

**Also:**

```
=if(and(sumif(H12, ">0")=True, sumif(I12,"BRB")=true), sum(I12))
```

Percent is my `H3:H` named range, and Style is my `I3:I` range.

Answer (score -2):

i think i got it, using sumifs